# Modal Window Link Re-directing not working in IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used both prototype windows and jquery thickbox windows for creating modal window effects and these are not working only in IE 6. I am passing a parameter at the end of the url, but that parameter passing it not working. If i remove the parameter and give a normal url, its working fine. Is there any other way to pass a parameter to get it working in IE 6..??

The sample code for jquery lightbox is like this..

```
tb_open_new('CopySolution/'+id+'?TB_iframe=true&height=140&width=500&modal=true')
```

Javascript Code of prototype windows

```
var renameWindow = null;
var solWindow;
function openRename(id, name, version) {
    renameWindow = new Window({maximizable: false, minimizable:false, 
        width:520, height:140, className: "dodo", show:false, 
        title: "${message:window.rename.title}",  
        url : "http://${serverName}${contextPath}/main/Rename/"+id 
    })
    renameWindow.setDestroyOnClose();
    renameWindow.showCenter();
    renameWindow.show(true);
    renameWindow.setURL(url);
}
```

please help...??

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use `showModalDialog()` to display a modal window:

[Pass Value From Parent Form to Child Form using javascript showModalDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490294/pass-value-from-parent-form-to-child-form-using-javascript-showmodaldialog/1490321#1490321)